# pywebview doesn't show anything

Tags: python-3.x, pywebview

I installed these libraries:

```
>pip freeze | findstr pythonnet
pythonnet==3.0.0a2
>pip freeze | findstr clr-loader
clr-loader==0.1.7
>pip freeze | findstr pywebview
pywebview==3.6.3
```

And I created a test.py with this content:
The code is:

```
import webview
webview.create_window('Hello world', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/')
webview.start()
```

I'm on Windows 10 and the result is a blank page:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbTo6.png)

Comment: Your image shows `Hello world` on the page.  What were you expecting the page to look like?

Comment: @j_b "hello world" is the title. I have to see this page: https://pywebview.flowrl.com/

Answer (score 0):

same here. In short:

Apparently the `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll` in the pip installed packages directory of `webview` (here: `c:/Users/<your_user>/AppData/Local/Packages/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0/LocalCache/local-packages/Python310/site-packages/webview/lib`) cannot find the respective `WebView2Loader.dll` in the arch subfolders `x64` or `x86` in this very directory.

Find out the arch of your `Microsoft WebView2 Runtime` (most likely `x64`) and just copy the dll from the respective subdirectory one up.

How can that be found out?

Add `try/except` block and add code for unsuccessful initialization of `CoreWebView2` (`args.InitializationException`) in `edgechromium.py` in the webview package, `edgechromium` is the default `gui` of the webview:

```
   def on_webview_ready(self, sender, args):
        try:
            logger.debug('### on_webview_ready')
            logger.debug('---> '+str(args.InitializationException))
            sender.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += self.on_new_window_request
            settings = sender.CoreWebView2.Settings
            settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = _debug['mode']
            settings.AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled = True
            settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = _debug['mode']
            settings.IsBuiltInErrorPageEnabled = True
            settings.IsScriptEnabled = True
            settings.IsWebMessageEnabled = True
            settings.IsStatusBarEnabled = _debug['mode']
            settings.IsZoomControlEnabled = True

            if _user_agent:
                settings.UserAgent = _user_agent

            if self.html:
                sender.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(self.html)

            logger.debug('-----------> '+str(sender.CoreWebView2))

        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(str(e))
```

This throws the error (german), the arg name can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.corewebview2initializationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1370.28)

```
[pywebview] ---> Die DLL "WebView2Loader.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.
   bei Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(String browserExecutableFolder, String userDataFolder, ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options, ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler en
vironment_created_handler)
   bei Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__13.MoveNext()
[pywebview] 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'NewWindowRequested'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\webview\platforms\edgechromium.py", line 153, in on_webview_ready
    sender.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += self.on_new_window_request
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'NewWindowRequested'
```